# permutation function does not return answers as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get all possible permutations for characters in a list. I need it to return all possible perms inside a list. A list of lists, where each component of the list is a permutation. Cant seem to figure out whats wrong with it. Tried playing around with the lists but nothing helps. Trying to get this done without importing anything.

the code:

```
def permutation(lst1, num_of_perms):
    if num_of_perms == len(lst1) - 1:
        print(lst1)

    for i in range(num_of_perms, len(lst1)):
        #  "removes" the first component of the list and returns all
        #  permutations where it is the first letter
        lst1[i], lst1[num_of_perms] = lst1[num_of_perms], lst1[i]
        #  swaps two components of the list each time.
        permutation(lst1, num_of_perms + 1)
        lst1[i], lst1[num_of_perms] = lst1[num_of_perms], lst1[i]
        #  swaps back before the next loop
```

Also i am open for any tips on how to improve the coding style.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Comment: thanks but im trying to get this done without itertools

Comment: You aren't *returning* anything; you are just printing a particular permutation.

Comment: Did your code run trough? It should give an indentation error after the "def permutation" statement

Comment: it did run through, the indentation only change when I uploaded the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between returning a value and printing a value, although the difference may be tricky to see if you are only running the function from the interactive interpreter, as it always prints the return value of a function to standard output.

The simplest fix would be to make `permutation` a generator function, as it simply involves replacing `print` with `yield`. You need to yield a *copy* of the list in the base case (otherwise, when you finally iterate the return value, you get references to whatever `lst1` refers to at that time, rather than what it referred to when you used `yield`). You also need to explicitly yield the values from the recursive call.

```
def permutation(lst1, num_of_perms):
    if num_of_perms == len(lst1) - 1:
        yield(lst1[:])

    for i in range(num_of_perms, len(lst1)):
        #  "removes" the first component of the list and returns all
        #  permutations where it is the first letter
        lst1[i], lst1[num_of_perms] = lst1[num_of_perms], lst1[i]
        #  swaps two components of the list each time.
        yield from permutation(lst1, num_of_perms + 1)
        lst1[i], lst1[num_of_perms] = lst1[num_of_perms], lst1[i]
        #  swaps back before the next loop
```

With those changes, you can make a list out of the generator itself:

```
>>> list(permutation([1,2,3],0))
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2]]
```

or iterate over it one permutation at a time

```
>>> for i, p in enumerate(permutation([1,2,3], 0)):
...   print("{}) {}".format(i, p))
...
0) [1, 2, 3]
1) [1, 3, 2]
2) [2, 1, 3]
3) [2, 3, 1]
4) [3, 2, 1]
5) [3, 1, 2]
```